# How to Javascript read ArrayList

Tags: javascript

I'm new to web development and just want to build a small website. I have found some javascript and want to expand but do not whatso what you do.

I have an ArrayList [word, size] and want to replace in var words {} where the path is.

Better formatting is:

```
How can a Javascript in ArrayList read and use as a variable?
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = 850;
  var height = 300;
    
  var color = d3.scale.category20();
  //var color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20,100])
  //.range(["#F00", "#E00", "#D00", "#C00", "#B00", "#A00", "#900", "#800", "#700", "#600", "#500", "#400"]);
  
  var words = [
    {"text":"study","size":40},
    {"text":"motion","size":15},
    {"text":"forces","size":10},
    {"text":"electricity","size":15},
    {"text":"movement","size":10},
    {"text":"relation","size":10},
    {"text":"things","size":10},
    {"text":"force","size":5},
    {"text":"ad","size":5},
    {"text":"energy","size":85},
    {"text":"living","size":10},
    {"text":"nonliving","size":10},
    {"text":"laws","size":15},
    {"text":"speed","size":45},
    {"text":"velocity","size":30},
    {"text":"define","size":10},
    {"text":"constraints","size":10},
    {"text":"universe","size":10},
    {"text":"physics","size":100},
    {"text":"describing","size":10},
    {"text":"matter","size":90},
    {"text":"physics-the","size":10}
  ];
  
  var vis = document.getElementById("wordcloud");
  var layout = d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
    .words(words)
    .padding(2)
    .rotate(function() { return (~~(Math.random() * 6) - 3) * 20; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .spiral("archimedean")
    .on("end", draw);
  
  layout.start();
  
  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("#wordcloud").append("svg")
      .style("width", "100%")
      .style("height", height+"px")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(words).enter().append("text")
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
      .style("font-family", "Impact")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
    ;
  }  
  
});
```

```
public class WebWordCloundAction extends ActionSupport {

public static ResultSet resultSet = null;
public static Statement statement = null;
public static Connection connection = null;

private static String urlDB ="";
private static String str1= null;
private static String str2= null;
public static  String url ="dat" ;
private static int count ;

private TreeMap<String,Integer> csv = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
private float minTag, maxTag;
private float smallestTag = 1;
private float largestTag = 100;



public String execute() throws Exception {

    urlDB = MainFunktion.urlDB;
    connection = MainFunktion.conn();

    minTag = 1;
    maxTag = 100;



    // mit blacklist            
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from webanwendung."+MainFunktion.tagCloud+" as u1 where u1.tagcloud_word not in (select u1.tagcloud_word from webanwendung."+MainFunktion.tagCloud+" as u1, webanwendung.blacklist as u2 where u1.tagcloud_word = u2.blacklist_wort);");       
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        str1 = resultSet.getString("tagcloud_word");
        str2 = resultSet.getString("tagcloud_number");
        count = Integer.parseInt(str2);
        csv.put(str1, count);               
    }



    MinMaxTag();    
    System.out.println("Word + Blacklist");     
    return "success";
}


public static String getUrlDB() {
    return urlDB;
}



public float getMinTag() {
    return minTag;
}



public void setMinTag(float minTag) {
    this.minTag = minTag;
}



public float getMaxTag() {
    return maxTag;
}



public void setMaxTag(float maxTag) {
    this.maxTag = maxTag;
}



public float getSmallestTag() {
    return smallestTag;
}



public void setSmallestTag(float smallestTag) {
    this.smallestTag = smallestTag;
}



public float getLargestTag() {
    return largestTag;
}



public void setLargestTag(float largestTag) {
    this.largestTag = largestTag;
}

public void MinMaxTag() {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : csv.entrySet()) {
          Integer value = entry.getValue();
          if(value < minTag && value > 0) {
              minTag = value;
          }
          if(value > maxTag) {
              maxTag = value;
          }
        }
}

public Map<String, Integer> getCsv() {
    return csv;
}
```

}

and the ArrayList is "csv" resultSet of Datenbank

Comment: Please don't post code as a screenshot. Post it as a code block or even better a snippet that reproduces your problem. We can not (easily) change your code when it's posted as a screenshot.

Comment: Can you post your code? The picture in not useful for US...thx

Comment: i posted my code

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a for loop as below

```
var usedWords = '';
for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++) {
    //condition to filter text what you want 
    usedWords = words[i].text;
}
```